# Get Second Last commit SHA of a branch using GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, cicd, rollback

I am trying to create a simple rollback workflow that will get the previous SHA of 'main' branch and deploy a docker image with that tag.
In my local machine this command works -

```bash
git rev-parse HEAD~1
```

And returns previous SHA. So I created a workflow around it to set output of a variable but now I am getting this error-

```bash
Run echo "prev_sha=$(git rev-parse HEAD~1)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

This is the workflow -

```yaml
on: workflow_dispatch

jobs:
  get_prev_sha:
    name: get previous sha of main
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      prev_sha: ${{ steps.prev_sha.outputs.prev_sha }}
    steps:      
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: 'main'

      - name: Get last commit SHA
        id: prev_sha
        run: |
          echo "prev_sha=$(git rev-parse HEAD~1)" >> "$GITHUB_OUTPUT"
```

My only question is, how do I get the previous (2nd last) hash of a branch using GitHub Actions and set is as output?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That error occurs when the Git project directory contains a single commit. My guess is that the environment created by Github to run actions does not contain the entire Git history for a project. It only contains the most recent commit.

Comment: Use `fetch-depth` of [actions/checkout@v4](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#checkout-v4) to fetch the number of commits you need. "**Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. Set `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all history for all branches and tags.**" See https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches and https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#checkout-head.

Comment: @Azeem You should make your comment an answer since it does answer the O.P.'s question. While I have used Github for a long time I was only guessing that it only checks out the commit being tested. Your comment confirms my guess. You deserve credit for that answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of [actions/checkout@v4](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#checkout-v4):

> Only a single commit is fetched by default, for the ref/SHA that triggered the workflow. Set `fetch-depth: 0` to fetch all history for all branches and tags.

and, here's the [usage](https://github.com/actions/checkout?tab=readme-ov-file#usage) of `fetch-depth`:

```yaml
# Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
# Default: 1
fetch-depth: ''
```

So, you can use `fetch-depth` to fetch the last two commits only i.e. `fetch-depth: 2` and `git rev-parse HEAD~1` should return the correct commit hash.